# add a template is not displaying in Azure dev ops latest

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I tried creating my own .MD files for a template to get for my branch PR's like an image below

in my develop branch

then I created one more branch based on it and did some changes and tried to create a pull request but the pull request is not showing the template but the default description as changed file name

I'm not able to see even Add a template dropdown
[image]

is I am missing any master settings and is this only available in paid accounts?

I was referring to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops&source=docs
so is it outdated in that case can you help me with the latest steps or link

Comment: Does your "development.md" also include some content? Can you add it to your question? Because you share additional.md but the pull request to the develop branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need save these .md files in the default branch.

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops#branch-specific-pull-request-templates): Branch specific pull request templates must be saved in the **default branch** of your repository using the following folder hierarchy: **pull_request_template/branches/**. These folders must be based in one of the following folders in your repository.

- A folder named `.azuredevops` that is contained in the root folder of
  the repository
- A folder named `.vsts` that is contained in the root folder of the
  repository
- A folder named `docs` that is contained in the root folder of the
  repository
- The root folder of the repository

And this is my test result:

[image]

**Update1**

According to the doc and my test result, we could only create template in the default branch like master, If we create template file in other branch, we cannot use it in the pull request.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Hi Vito Liu-MSFT 
Excellent and thank you, it worked for me but can't we do something like 
even my branch can have some separate template along with what provided by master

Comment: Hi @ksk, We cannot save template file in other branches, I have updated the answer, you could check it. If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it. Thanks